# column-wise correlation between all pairs of columns of two data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Hi so I have created a function to check the correlation between 2 variables, anyone knows how can I create a new data frame from this?

```
In [1]:from scipy.stats import pearsonr
for colY in Y.columns:
    for colX in X.columns:
    #print('Pearson Correlation')
        corr, _ = pearsonr(numerical_cols_target[colX], numerical_cols_target[colY])
        alpha = 0.05
        print('Pearson Correlation', (alpha, corr))
        if corr <= alpha:
            print(colX +' and ' +colY+ ' two ariables are not correlated ')
        else:
            print(colX +' and ' +colY+ ' two variables are highly correlated ')
        print('\n')
    print('\n')
```

here's a sample output from the correlation function:

````
Out [1]: 
Pearson Correlation (0.05, -0.1620045985125294)
banana and orange are not correlated 

Pearson Correlation (0.05, 0.2267582070839226)
apple and orange are highly correlated
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using two for loops. Depending on the size of your dataset this will be very slow.

Pandas provides a correlation function with might come in hand here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(4), 'B': [2*i for i in range(4)]})
```

using corr() will give you the pairwise correlations then **and returns a new dataframe as well**:

```
df.corr()
```

For more infos you can check the manual: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=X.columns, columns=Y.columns)

#In your loop
df[colY][colX] = corr
```

Your loop would then be

```py
for colY in Y.columns:
    for colX in X.columns:
    #print('Pearson Correlation')
        corr, _ = pearsonr(numerical_cols_target[colX], numerical_cols_target[colY])
        alpha = 0.05
        print('Pearson Correlation', (alpha, corr))
        df[colY][colX] = corr
        if corr <= alpha:
            print(colX +' and ' +colY+ ' two ariables are not correlated ')
        else:
            print(colX +' and ' +colY+ ' two variables are highly correlated ')
        print('\n')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:
This will get a column-wise correlation of every two pairs of columns between X and Y dataframes and create another dataframe that keeps all the correlations and whether they pass a threshold alpha:
This assumes Y has less or equal number of columns as X. If not simply switch X and Y places:

```
import collections
corr_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col_X', 'col_Y', 'corr', 'is_correlated'])
d = collections.deque(X.columns)
Y_cols = Y.columns
alpha = 0.05
for i in range(len(d)):
  d.rotate(i)
  X = X[d]
  corr = Y.corrwith(X, axis=0)
  corr_df = corr_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'col_X':list(d)[:len(Y_cols)], 'col_Y':Y.columns, 'corr':corr[:len(Y_cols)], 'is_correlated':corr[:len(Y_cols)]>alpha}))
print(corr_df.reset_index())
```

sample input and output:

```
X:
   A  B   C
0  2  2  10
1  4  0   2
2  8  0   1
3  0  0   8

Y:
   B   C
0  2  10
1  0   2
2  0   1
3  0   8


correlation(X, Y):

  col_X col_Y  corr is_correlated
0     A     B   1.0          True
1     B     C   1.0          True
2     C     B   1.0          True
3     A     C   1.0          True
4     A     B   1.0          True
5     B     C   1.0          True
```