# Applying across a numpy axis (row-wise correlation of every pair of rows between two arrays with NaNs)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've got a function `f(x,y)` that takes two 1-d arrays and returns a scalar.

If I have a 2d matrix of shape `(M,N)`, how do I efficiently apply the function pairwise across the `0` axis to end up with a square symmetric result of shape `(M, M)`?

Edit:

I'm trying to calculate pairwise correlation of an array of 1d arrays:

```
def f(x, y):
    sigma_x_y = np.nanstd(x) * np.nanstd(y)
    covariance = np.nanmean((x-np.nanmean(x))*(y-np.nanmean(y)))
    return covariance/sigma_x_y
```

Comment: `M` is the shape of axis=0 and not the number of axis. As for your function, it generally depends on the function itself. Maybe you can provide us a minimal code of f(x,y) and desired output to help us understand better. Thank you

Comment: Added code, thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you. And do you want the output between EVERY pair of rows of x and y to be stored in a MxM array? Do you not want to use builtin functions for it? does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080994/column-wise-correlation-between-all-pairs-of-columns-of-two-data-frame/62082931#62082931 help you?

Comment: Also how big are x and y and how much performance/memory is an issue (the optimal answer can be different)?

Comment: Small- it's about 3000x3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. The equations are similar to your function f(x, y):

```
x_m = x - np.nanmean(x,axis=1)[:,None]
y_m = y - np.nanmean(y,axis=1)[:,None]

X = np.nansum(x_m**2,axis=1)
Y = np.nansum(y_m**2,axis=1)

corr = np.dot(x_m,y_m.T)/np.sqrt(np.dot(X[:,None],Y[None]))
```

***EDIT***: If you wish to ignore NaN values in calculating correlation of two rows, simply replace last line with this:

```
corr = np.dot(np.nan_to_num(x_m), np.nan_to_num(y_m).T)/np.sqrt(np.dot(X[:,None],Y[None]))
```

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure this is right; it should take in an `MxN` array, not `x` and `y`...

Comment: @cjm2671 have `x` and `y` be a `MxN` arrays. It is just variable name. Please let me know if the output is not as expected. Maybe you can provide a sample input/output. Thank you.

Comment: So running it as f(x,x) actually does produce almost the right result, except there are a lot of nan's where the series contain `nan`. The idea behind using this (and not `np.corrcoef`) is that it is just calculates on the sections available (like `pd.corr`).

Comment: @cjm2671 can you elaborate on how you want to deal with nans when a row has a cell with nan value? Do you want to ignore nans (and corresponding value in the other array) and just use non-NaN values of two arrays to calculate the correlation?

Comment: @cjm2671 please fine EDIT on my post to see if addresses your issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's producing the right numbers! I have a question though: for the denominator, surely it should be some kind of `nanstd()`. Can you help me understand the denominator? I think it should be equivalent to `M * sigma_x * sigma_y`. I added my own (less elegant) version above so you can see my own thinking.

Comment: @cjm2671 You are welcome. I think it is taken care of when you use `X` and `Y` which uses `np.nansum` and `np.nanmean` in `x_m`/`y_m` to calculate the std of `x` and `y` while ignoring NaNs. That is what `X` and `Y` are supposed to be. Is that what you are referring to?